# MEAN Full Stack app not deploying on Heroku Application Error

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, heroku, mongoose

I am trying to deploy my mean stack application with backend database using mongodb on heroku but it gives application error.I have pasted the logs of heroku and my package.json file.

---

**Heroku logs:**

```
2020-09-02T07:29:30.163006+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the mean-app@0.0.0 start script.
2020-09-02T07:29:30.163090+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There 
is likely additional logging output above.
2020-09-02T07:29:30.172713+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-09-02T07:29:30.172942+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-09-02T07:29:30.173226+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-09-02T07_29_30_164Z- 
debug.log
2020-09-02T07:29:30.223791+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-09-02T07:29:30.260565+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-09-02T07:35:27.123519+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-09-02T07:35:31.746958+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2020-09-02T07:35:34.033496+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-09-02T07:35:34.033513+00:00 app[web.1]: > mean-app@0.0.0 start /app
2020-09-02T07:35:34.033514+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2020-09-02T07:35:34.033514+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-09-02T07:35:34.211459+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:968
2020-09-02T07:35:34.211461+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2020-09-02T07:35:34.211461+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2020-09-02T07:35:34.211462+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-09-02T07:35:34.211462+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'mongoose'
2020-09-02T07:35:34.211462+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2020-09-02T07:35:34.211463+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/backend/models/post.js
2020-09-02T07:35:34.211463+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/backend/app.js
2020-09-02T07:35:34.211464+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/server.js
2020-09-02T07:35:34.211464+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:965:15)
2020-09-02T07:35:34.211465+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:841:27)
2020-09-02T07:35:34.211465+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)
2020-09-02T07:35:34.211465+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
2020-09-02T07:35:34.211466+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/backend/models/post.js:2:18)
2020-09-02T07:35:34.211466+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
2020-09-02T07:35:34.211467+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
2020-09-02T07:35:34.211467+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
2020-09-02T07:35:34.211467+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
2020-09-02T07:35:34.211468+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19) {
2020-09-02T07:35:34.211468+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2020-09-02T07:35:34.211468+00:00 app[web.1]: requireStack: [
2020-09-02T07:35:34.211469+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/backend/models/post.js',
2020-09-02T07:35:34.211469+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/backend/app.js',
2020-09-02T07:35:34.211470+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/server.js'
2020-09-02T07:35:34.211470+00:00 app[web.1]: ]
2020-09-02T07:35:34.211470+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2020-09-02T07:35:34.220729+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2020-09-02T07:35:34.221090+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2020-09-02T07:35:34.223600+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! mean-app@0.0.0 start: `node server.js`
2020-09-02T07:35:34.223754+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2020-09-02T07:35:34.223917+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2020-09-02T07:35:34.224043+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the mean-app@0.0.0 start script.
2020-09-02T07:35:34.224189+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There 
is likely additional logging output above.
2020-09-02T07:35:34.235076+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-09-02T07:35:34.235345+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-09-02T07:35:34.235483+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-09-02T07_35_34_225Z- 
debug.log
2020-09-02T07:35:34.294877+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-09-02T07:35:34.336381+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-09-02T07:35:34.338258+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-09-02T07:35:41.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-09-02T07:35:42.772327+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2020-09-02T07:35:46.548576+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-09-02T07:35:46.548586+00:00 app[web.1]: > mean-app@0.0.0 start /app
2020-09-02T07:35:46.548586+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2020-09-02T07:35:46.548586+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-09-02T07:35:46.821836+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:968
2020-09-02T07:35:46.821878+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2020-09-02T07:35:46.821879+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2020-09-02T07:35:46.821879+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-09-02T07:35:46.821879+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'mongoose'
2020-09-02T07:35:46.821880+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2020-09-02T07:35:46.821885+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/backend/models/post.js
2020-09-02T07:35:46.821885+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/backend/app.js
2020-09-02T07:35:46.821886+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/server.js
2020-09-02T07:35:46.821890+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:965:15)
2020-09-02T07:35:46.821890+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:841:27)
2020-09-02T07:35:46.821894+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)
2020-09-02T07:35:46.821894+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
2020-09-02T07:35:46.821894+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/backend/models/post.js:2:18)
2020-09-02T07:35:46.821895+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
2020-09-02T07:35:46.821895+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
2020-09-02T07:35:46.821895+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
2020-09-02T07:35:46.821896+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
2020-09-02T07:35:46.821896+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19) {
2020-09-02T07:35:46.821896+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2020-09-02T07:35:46.821896+00:00 app[web.1]: requireStack: [
2020-09-02T07:35:46.821897+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/backend/models/post.js',
2020-09-02T07:35:46.821897+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/backend/app.js',
2020-09-02T07:35:46.821897+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/server.js'
2020-09-02T07:35:46.821898+00:00 app[web.1]: ]
2020-09-02T07:35:46.821898+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2020-09-02T07:35:46.847916+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2020-09-02T07:35:46.848347+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2020-09-02T07:35:46.852389+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! mean-app@0.0.0 start: `node server.js`
2020-09-02T07:35:46.852586+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2020-09-02T07:35:46.852827+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2020-09-02T07:35:46.853679+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the mean-app@0.0.0 start script.
2020-09-02T07:35:46.853832+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There 
is likely additional logging output above.
2020-09-02T07:35:46.861650+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-09-02T07:35:46.861954+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-09-02T07:35:46.862058+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-09-02T07_35_46_855Z- 
debug.log
2020-09-02T07:35:46.927186+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-09-02T07:35:47.116783+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Here is script of package.json file of angular app.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "mean-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "start:server": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~10.0.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^10.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "~10.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "~10.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.0.2",
    "@angular/material": "^10.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "~10.0.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongodb": "^3.5.9",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.5",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1000.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.0.2",
    "@types/angular": "^1.7.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0-next.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.25",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.9.5"
  }
}
```

Please suggest me any solution so that it can be resolved.

Comment: can u share the folder structure

Comment: - .browserslistrc
- .editorconfig
- .gitignore
- .vscode
- angular.json
- backend
- e2e
- karma.conf.js
- node_modules
- package-lock.json
- package.json
- README.md
- server.js
- src
- tsconfig.app.json
- tsconfig.base.json
- tsconfig.json
- tsconfig.spec.json
- tslint.json

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling mongoose, don't use the -g label.

```
npm install mongoose --save
```

Basically, the error is that mongoose is not installed on the heroku server.

Answer (score 0):

You have installed mongoose as a `devDependency`. When Heroku builds your project it prunes away all your devDependencies, so at the time of execution, mongoose is undefined.

Make sure to move mongoose to `dependencies`.

I would run `npm uninstall mongoose` and then `npm i mongoose` to install to your `dependencies` list